# Парсинг сайта understat.com

Tags: python-3.x, парсер

Хочу распарсить страницу https://understat.com/team/Arsenal/
Интересуют два крайних правых столбца xG90 и xA90(см скриншот)
[image: Нужные данные]

В html коде страницы эти данные есть, но в текстовом виде нет. [image: Так выглядит текст]

Подскажите, как подступиться?

Comment: Это и есть текстовый вид, берите и пользуйтесь

Comment: Если вас смущает экранирование строкового литерала, вы всегда можете его снять с помощью например `json.loads`

Comment: Передал руками в json.loads и получилось то, что надо. Осталось выяснить, как эту строчку получить не руками, но все равно спасибо